# Jython naming conflict: java.lang.Runtime.exec and python's exec

Tags: python, jython, naming

I am translating some java code into Jython and there is a point where I need to call java.lang.Runtime. The code in Java reads:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I need this to translate to Jython, but it confuses "exec" with Python's built in exec function. I searched and found suggestions to use something like -

```
from java.lang.Runtime import exec as javaExec
```

or

```
import java.lang.Runtime.exec as javaExec
```

but the first still confuses the two versions of exec, and the second doesn't allow for the call to getRuntime().

Is there a way to write this line in Jython by either using Python's functions or Java's functions without the naming conflict?

Answer (score 3):

```
javaexec = getattr(Runtime.getRuntime(), "exec")
```

That should work. Even better:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```